# Dataflow JAVA SDK : Take the code as an input, process at the backed

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Please support me to understand the implementation of following scenario.

Suppose the user types the code written using data flow SDK commands in a text box at the front end.
We need to get that code (let's say as a string) and execute at the back end.
Does Data flow SDK provide a facility like a execution manager, to do such a thing?
Also some resources to get familiar with such an implementation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow does not support the kind of dynamic evaluation of user code described in your question.  In order to run a Dataflow job using the Java SDK, user code is compiled at the client, packaged into a .jar file, and distributed to the worker machines.