# Interpret Dataflow JAVA SDK commands with JAVA REPL

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop, google-cloud-dataflow

[Java-REPL](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl) give the ability to recognize,interpret and run the java commands user entering from the UI. Suppose we need to run some java commands provided by special SDK using [Java-REPL](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl). In my case, I want to run commands which contain methods provided by [Google Dataflow SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK).
How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to [Dataflow JAVA SDK : Take the code as an input, process at the backed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796798/dataflow-java-sdk-take-the-code-as-an-input-process-at-the-backed) addresses a similar problem.  The code for the job is packaged at job startup.

Please note that for streaming pipelines, however, you can use the [pipeline update](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline) feature to change the logic of your job.